# rails svg not acceptable

Tags: svg, http-status-code-406

I am using google maps api and for the marker I am trying to use an svg file

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coords, map: map, icon: '/assets/pin/pin.svg' 
  });
```

The image actually is been displayed but I am getting a console error.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/pin.svg 406 (Not Acceptable)
```

The request headers

```
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the icon requres a `url`
e.g.

```
var myIcon={
    url: 'pin.svg',
    size: new google.maps.Size(10, 10),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(5, 5)
    };
```

Then,

```
var myMarker= new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: location,
            map: MyMap,
            icon: myIcon
        });
```